# Closed form of this binomial expression?

Tags: closed-form, binomial-theorem

Does a closed form for this binomial expression exists?

$\sum_{K=2}^{N}\binom{N}{K}P^{K}(1-P)^{N-K}$

Thank you.

Comment: By Binomial Theorem, equals $$(1+P-P)^N-{N\choose 1}P(1-P)^{N-1}-{N\choose 0}(1-P)^N = 1-NP(1-P)^{N-1}-(1-P)^N$$ $$=1-(1-P)^{N-1}(1+(N-1)P).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sum ran from $K=0$ to $K=N$, you’d simply have $\big(P+(1-P)\big)^N=1$ by the binomial theorem. It’s missing the first two terms, so it must be equal to

$$1-\binom{N}0P^0(1-P)^N-\binom{N}1P(1-P)^{N-1}=1-(1-P)^N-NP(1-P)^{N-1}\;.$$